# how to re position column placed in datawindow usind editor source in run time?

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc, powerbuilder-conversion

i have created a datawindow dynamically(using Source Editor) in powerbuilder 12.5. now what i want now is when user runs the application and see the output datawindow now if user drage some column and reposition it it works because column is moving column. now for the next time when he run the applicaiton the reposition columns comes to its origional place. which is not my requirement i want the changed watawindow.
i used the term as file saving of datawindow source code which is a  XHTML file ..
Any helping guide would be highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the changed columns in either a text file or database table to recreate it again at runtime.  The positional data could be something similar to 'colname1x':1,'colname1y':25,'colname1width':250,'colname1height':35,...

Then at runtime before the dw is rendered you would make all columns invisible, then go through your list making them visible and positioning them per the previously saved information.